Haskell debug adapter not found
I have followed the instructions on this site: https://www.haskell.org/get-started/ to set up haskell in VS code. When I try to run the haskell project I get a VS Code error message:

haskell-debug-adapter is not found. Does your shell recognize haskell-debug-adapter?

How do I fix this?
I have debugger installed, I have tried searching the web but with no results. It works fine when started from the VS code terminal but I am unable to run it using the 'run' button in Vs code

When you say you have the debugger installed and that it works fine when started from the VS code terminal, what do you mean?  Do you mean that the command haskell-debug-adapter --version works from the VS code terminal?

I meant that I can run my .hs file by typing 'ghc filename.hs' in the VS coode terminal to compile it and then just calling the created .exe file, but when I try to run it by clicking the 'run' button I get that message.

It looks like you've installed the "Haskell GHCi Debug Adapter Phoityne" VS code extension but haven't yet followed its setup instructions.  (It's easy to end up in this situation -- when you first try to "Run and Debug", I think you're given an option to install this extension and little or no opportunity to review the instructions.)
So, locate this extension in your list of installed extensions and click on it.  You should get a page of instructions about running stack install haskell-dap ghci-dap haskell-debug-adapter or cabal install ghci-dap haskell-debug-adapter.
The installation instructions make it seem like you only need to install these support programs once, globally, and then they'll work on any project.  However, these packages depend on specific GHC versions, and if you try to use them on a project with a different GHC version, you'll get weird messages about failure to launch GHCi (mismatched interface files or other errors).  The problem is partially documented in this issue.  The solution seems to be to reinstall the packages from within the project directory.  If you switch between multiple projects with different GHC version, that means reinstalling after every project switch!  Alternatively, you can hardcode a path in each project's launch.json  file.  It's a lot messier than it needs to be, that's for sure!
